# Create json object from categories and subcategories added to mongodb with hierarchy

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I created categories in mongoDB using node, Added parent property to every insert to determine which is the parent category.

```
[{ _id: 5889a06f274afdfd6f2bf249,
    cat_id: 1,
    title: 'Parent Category',
    description: '',
    parent: null,
    status: 1}]

[{ _id: 5889a06f274afdfd6f2bf249,
    cat_id: 1,
    title: 'Child Category',
    description: '',
    parent: 1,
    status: 1}]
```

Now the output json should be using node when I query using db.find() method of mongoDB.

```
{
  obj: [
  { 
    _id: "5889a06f274afdfd6f2bf249",
    cat_id: 1,
    title: "Parent Category",
    description: "",
    parent: null,
    status: 1, 
    subcategories: [
      { 
        _id: "5889a06f274afdfd6f2bf249",
        cat_id: 1,
        title: "Child Category",
        description: "",
        parent: 1,
        status: 1

      }
    ]

  }
]}
```

Comment: Depending on which version of MongoDB you should be able to use [**`$graphLookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#pipe._S_graphLookup) for this task.

Comment: I have modules created in node and using rest api to call methods

`//Get Categories
module.exports.getCategories = function(callback, limit){
    Categories.find(function(err, data){
       
    }).limit(limit);
}`


And calling this from api js 

    `app.get('/api/categories', function(req, res){
      Categories.getCategories(function(err, categories){
          if(err){
              throw err;
          }
          res.json(categories);
      })
  });`

Comment: Code is ready and returning the result but wrong set of data.
Not able to understand what exactly the mistake is.

`Categories.aggregate( [
       {
          $graphLookup: {
             from: "categories",
             startWith: "$parent",
             connectFromField: "cat_id",
             connectToField: "parent",
             as: "subCategory"
          }
       }
    ], callback )`

There should be list of categories which parent is null which then holds categories as children which parent matches with cat_id of parent categories.

Comment: @RohitDhore: Have you got the idea how to achieve the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like below.

`$startWith` expression value for each input document is matched against the `connectToField`.

For each matching document, the `connectFromField` value is matched recursively against the `connectToField` value in the  collection.

Collection

```
{ "_id" : 1, "cat_id" : 1, "title" : "Parent Category", "parent" : null }
{ "_id" : 2, "cat_id" : 2, "title" : "Child Category", "parent" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3, "cat_id" : 3, "title" : "Sub Child Category", "parent" : 2 }
```

Query

```
Categories.aggregate([{
    $graphLookup: {
        from: "categories",
        startWith: "$cat_id",
        connectFromField: "cat_id",
        connectToField: "parent",
        as: "subCategory"
    }
}], callback)
```

Output

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "cat_id": 1,
    "title": "Parent Category",
    "parent": null,
    "subCategory": [{
        "_id": 3,
        "cat_id": 3,
        "title": "Sub Child Category",
        "parent": 2
    }, {
        "_id": 2,
        "cat_id": 2,
        "title": "Child Category",
        "parent": 1
    }]
} {
    "_id": 2,
    "cat_id": 2,
    "title": "Child Category",
    "parent": 1,
    "subCategory": [{
        "_id": 3,
        "cat_id": 3,
        "title": "Sub Child Category",
        "parent": 2
    }]
} {
    "_id": 3,
    "cat_id": 3,
    "title": "Sub Child Category",
    "parent": 2,
    "subCategory": []
}
```

Comment: I am looking for different output where all categories having parent null comes first and each null parent categories will have subcategories where parent id is matching to there cat_id. See output below